# What is BJ_Shadow in JBD2 context?

Tags: c, buffer, ext4, journaling

I am studying the jbd2 source code, and I could not understand what the `BJ_Shadow` flag means for a given `buffer_head`.

Is `BJ_Shadow` a copy of the given `buffer_head` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a buffer is in `BJ_Shadow` state, it means that there is a copy-out of this buffer being written to the disk.

So, basically when the transaction is committing, the buffer head (BH) going to be written is in the `BJ_Metadata` state, and the committing thread will make a copy of this BH to be used for the IO submission. After the copy is made, the transaction changes the state of the BH to `BJ_Shadow`, and finally the last state after IO completion is the `BJ_Forget` state.